# Ruby Rails - JS - stop previous scripts in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this altered javascript to count up timer. Scripts works alright. But I am using this in an ajax response. When I run an ajax query first time, I get JS in response and this clock runs fine. But when I make more requests after that first request, then the timer gets confused, as if there are multiple setInterval are running, and that causes uncontrolled counting, stats running faster after every new ajax response rather than smoothly counting up by steps of seconds. How do I get around this?

```
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
  s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2);
return s;
}

function clock() {
++startNumber;

  DisplayStr = displayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(startNumber,86400,100000));

        t = calcage(startNumber,3600,24);
        if (t < 10) {
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, "0"+t);
        } else {
        DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, t);
        }

        t = calcage(startNumber,60,60);
        if (t < 10) {
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, "0"+t);
        } else {
        DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, t);
        }

        t = calcage(startNumber,1,60);
        if (t < 10) {
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, "0"+t);
        } else {
        DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, t);
        }

$("#counter").html(DisplayStr);
}

$('#view').html(<%= (render :partial => 'ajax_response').to_json.html_safe %>);
#partial render and read "#timer" value as integer to start ahead. "#timer" is in "#view" div
$(function(){
c = $("#timer").val();
startNumber = parseFloat(c);
displayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%%:%%M%%:%%S%%";
var int=self.setInterval("clock()",1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there *are* multiple intervals running. You need to clear the interval when you want it to stop by doing `clearInterval(int)`. Either that, or making sure you only run `setInterval` once for any given function.

Also, besides the point, but having strings as parameters to `setInterval` is a Bad Thing (tm). Use `setInterval(clock, 1000)` instead.

Also #2, can I just say a word how confusing it is having a variable called `int`, even if it's completely legal? :P

Comment: That was a bad bad variable name. :P
Ok. So I tried `clearInterval(int);`. Seems like its killing the whole thing. Every new ajax response shall check in there is an counter running, if so then use that or stop that. What the best place to put `clearInterval(int);`?

Comment: Thing is, I am not sure what you want to do :)